# Is it possible for two users to update separate records in the same transaction?

Tags: trigger, triggercontext, transaction

This requires a little context... I want to create a trigger that only fires when one record is being updated. It's a trigger that shouldn't be fired with bulk data manipulation. I've set it up so that as long as the size of the list of opportunities is equal to one, execute the code.

My concern is that two different users could potentially edit separate opportunities at the exact same time and they would be included in the same transaction. In this case, there would be more than one opportunity and the trigger logic wouldn't fire as expected. Is this situation (although highly unlikely) possible?

I'm pretty sure it is not and that a transaction will only be for one user at a time, but wanted to be certain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each transaction will occur with exactly one user. Two simultaneous edits on two different records will result in two simultaneous transactions occurring in parallel.