# How triggers start firing?

Tags: apex, trigger, transaction

Is it guaranteed that when we create/update/delete two different records separately but in one time and from one user create/update/delete trigger fires twice? Or two these operation can be merged in one trigger firing?

I know that my question almost duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53886/is-it-possible-for-two-users-to-update-separate-records-in-the-same-transaction) But I need proofs from documentation If it is possible, beacause unfortunately I didn't find any information about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such guarantee in the documentation, as far as I can tell. However, Salesforce literally could not function properly if it were otherwise. Keep in mind that a transaction is much more than just triggers (validation rules, assignment rules, workflow rules, rollup summaries, process builders, etc). Also, there are many functions that could not operate properly under this premise. For example, what would UserInfo.getUserId() return if two transactions coalesced? Clearly that must not happen, so there's no way they could simultaneously guarantee the behavior of these methods and combine transactions. Also, there'd be increased risk of database contention trying to marry together transactions on the same object that happen to fire in the same 1/1000th of a second window, with no real benefits to performance.

Comment: thnx for the answer sfdcfox, now it is more claerly for me